# ADAccount inactive accounts piping through ADUser issue

Tags: powershell

I did some PowerShell script to find inactive users in AD that are 90 days old looping through all DCs to also get LastLogon attribute. I also need some extra attributes that only ADUser can bring out. I've got an error when running my script with the piping in the `$users = Search-ADAccount` line.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function Get-ADUsersLastLogon() {
  $dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter {Name -like "*"}
  $OUs = @()
  $OU += "ou=Users-A,ou=Users,ou=Items,dc=mydc,dc=com"
  $OU += "ou=Users-B,ou=Users,ou=Items,dc=mydc,dc=com"

  $time = 0
  $exportFilePath = "c:\tmp\lastLogon-test $(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy).csv"
  $columns = "name;username;whencreated;whenchanged;DNname;datetime"
  #InactiveTest
  $InactiveFilter = @{
      UsersOnly = $true
      AccountInactive = $true
      TimeSpan = New-Timespan -Days 90
  }
  #EndInactiveTest
  Out-File -FilePath $exportFilePath -Force -InputObject $columns

  foreach ($OU in $OUs) {
    $users = Search-ADAccount @InactiveFilter |
             Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OUs -Property displayName, whenCreated, whenChanged
    foreach ($user in $users) {
      foreach($dc in $dcs) { 
        $hostname = $dc.HostName
        $currentUser = Get-ADUser $user.SamAccountName |
                       Get-ADObject -Server $hostname -Properties lastLogon
        if ($currentUser.LastLogon -gt $time) {
          $time = $currentUser.LastLogon
        }
      }

      $dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($time)
      $row = $user.displayName + ";" + $user.SamAccountName + ";" +
             $user.whenCreated + ";" + $user.whenChanged + ";" +
             $user.distinguishedName + ";" + $dt

      Out-File -FilePath $exportFilePath -Append -NoClobber -InputObject $row

      $time = 0
    }
  }
}

Get-ADUsersLastLogon
```

Comment: You are running the loop using wrong variable names `foreach($OUs in $OUs)`. That should be `foreach($OU in $OUs)` and use the singular `$OU` inside the loop. Now you are using `-SearchBase` giving it an array of OU Distinghuished Names. You can also use `$OUs | Foreach-Object {...}` and use the automatic variable `$_` inside the loop. Also, have a look at [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6) instead of creating the csv file using `Out-File`

Comment: ..And.. What is the use of the `foreach($dc in $dcs)` loop when all it does is getting a user object and overwrite the last logon time variable `$time` for each dc in the array? Now, you are only recording the values taken from the last values dc in the collection.

Comment: *"I've got an error when running my script"* That error being ... *what?*

Comment: Many thanks Theo :-) About the foreach($dc in $dcs) it's a loop to go through all DCs to find the latest LastLogon info (this attribute doesn't replicate on all DCs).                                                                             I've changed under $OUs=@() the variables $OUS to $OU and also the foreach with ($OU in $OUs) like suggested. I now run my script and the cvs output only has the $column info (name;username,...) in it, script finishes without errors.

Comment: I still see `foreach ($OUs in $OUs) {..}` and `-SearchBase $OUs`.. Did you edit the code in the question to reflect the changes?

Comment: Hello again Ansgar :-) If I rollback the changes proposed by Theo, here's the error I get : Get-ADUser : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match an
y of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At C:\GetAllDC-UsersLastLogon.ps
+ $users = Search-ADAccount @InactiveFilter | Get-ADUser <<<<  -SearchBase $OUs -Property displayName, whenCreated, whenChanged +CategoryInfo:InvalidArgument: (CN=TestTest,OU=...mydc,DC=com:PSObject) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException

Comment: Theo, just did it now to reflect changes in my script :-)

Comment: The issue seems to be with the construction of $users = Search-ADAccount @InactiveFilter | Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OUs -Property displayName, whenCreated, whenChanged
but I don't see the issue... :-(

Comment: If I do remove the ADAccount part like this : $users=Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OUs -Property displayName, whenCreated, whenChanged     It works but I do need the filter for inactive user accounts...

Comment: Please do not bury information that is relevant to your question in comments. [Edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think iterating through DC's and OU's and then collecting only the inactive users last logon dates could best be done using a Hashtable object as intermediate storage.

This helps avoiding duplicate entries and gives the opportunity to compare the LastLogonDate properties.

For the final output, it uses one single cmdlet called `Export-Csv`.

Below my (untested) code:

```
function Get-ADUsersLastLogon {
    # get your ad domain
    $DomainName = (Get-ADDomain).DNSRoot
    # get all DC hostnames as string array
    $DCs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $DomainName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hostname
    # create an array of OU distinghuished names used as SearchBase
    $OUs = "OU=Users-A,OU=Users,OU=Items,DC=mydc,DC=com", "OU=Users-B,OU=Users,OU=Items,DC=mydc,DC=com"
    $exportFilePath = "c:\tmp\lastLogon-test $(Get-Date -Format dd-MM-yyyy).csv"

    $InactiveFilter = @{
        UsersOnly       = $true
        AccountInactive = $true
        TimeSpan        = New-Timespan -Days 90
    }

    # use a lookup Hashtable to eliminate duplicates and collect only the latest logon dates
    $lookup = @{}

    # loop through the list of dc's
    foreach ($dc in $DCs) {
        # loop through the list of OU's
        foreach ($ou in $OUs) {
            $users = Search-ADAccount @InactiveFilter -SearchBase $ou -Server $dc
            foreach($user in $users) {
                # get the properties we want from the AD User. 
                # using the PowerShell property names, we get the dates already converted into DateTime objects.
                $usr = Get-ADUser -Identity $user.DistinguishedName -Server $dc -Properties DisplayName, Created, Modified, LastLogonDate |
                        Select-Object @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = {$_.DisplayName}},
                                        SamAccountName,
                                        @{Name = 'WhenCreated'; Expression = {$_.Created}},
                                        @{Name = 'WhenChanged'; Expression = {$_.Modified}},
                                        @{Name = 'DistinguishedName'; Expression = {$_.DistinguishedName}},
                                        @{Name = 'LastLogon'; Expression = {$_.LastLogonDate}}
                if ($usr) {
                    if ($lookup.ContainsKey($($user.DistinguishedName))) {
                        # we have collected this user before 
                        $lastLogon = $lookup[$($user.DistinguishedName)].LastLogon
                        if ($lastLogon) {
                            if (($usr.LastLogon) -and $lastLogon -lt $usr.LastLogon) {
                                # only store this new instance if the $user.LastLogon property is of a later date
                                $lookup[$($user.DistinguishedName)] = $usr
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        # this is a new user, so add the object to the HashTable
                        $lookup[$($user.DistinguishedName)] = $usr
                    }
                }
                else {
                    # should never happen..
                    Write-Warning "User $($user.SamAccountName) not found."
                }
            }
        }
    }

    # export the objects contained in the $lookup Hashtable as CSV
    ($output = foreach ($key in $lookup.Keys) {
        $lookup.$key
    }) | Export-Csv -Path $exportFilePath -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';' -Encoding UTF8 -Force

}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi Theo, thanks for this full script :-) I get an error when running it: Export-csv: cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null :-/

Comment: @Voilier Can you check if the $lookup hash gets filled?

Comment: @Voilier, sorry, I think I made a mistake. The test should have been `if (($usr.LastLogon) -and $lastLogon -lt $usr.LastLogon)`. I have updated the answer

Comment: Hey you're helping so that's already great, no worries :-) I've corrected the line but still get the same error: cannot bind argument to parameter "Path" because it is null :-/

Comment: @Voilier That is not the same error.. Now it complains about parameter `-Path`. Are you sure the path you have set in `$exportFilePath` points to an existing directory? Are the names in the `$OUs` array correct OU Distinghuished names?

Comment: Paths are correct both for $exportfilepath and OUs. Here's the full error, it is the same, apologies for not putting it fully in the comment:

Comment: Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Users\oms\Documents\testTuesday.ps1:63 char:30
+         }) | Export-Csv -Path <<<<  $exportFilePath -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';' -Encoding UTF8 -Force
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: @Voilier Please have a look at the updated answer. I was kind of blind I guess, because the part where the export takes place was _outside_ the function before. That is why the locally defined `$exportFilePath` was null. Moved it up now so it is the last action of the function.

Comment: I've got to the point of narrowing the issue and can now point to the loop with OUs  "foreach($OU in $OUs)" as the source of the problem. Everything works until I add this to the script... hmmm...<thinking>...

Comment: @Voilier Do you perhaps have any disallowed characters in the OU Distinghuished Names, like: a Number sign `#` at the beginning of the string, Leading or trailing spaces, a Comma `,`, a Double quote `"`, Less than symbol `<`, Plus sign `+`, Greater than symbol `>`, a Backslash character or Semicolon `;`? In that case, you need to escape them by prepending these characters with a backslash. Also the Equal sign `=` if it is part of a name should be escaped. (NOT the `=` sign after `OU=`, `DC=` etc. of course)

Comment: Thanks Theo, I've resolved it by using "foreach ($element in $OUs)". All works fine now, many MANY thanks for your time, help and solution :-)

Comment: @Voilier Good to hear! Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

@voilier Sorry, I don't understand how it works for you. Pasted your code and Get-ADUser cmdlet expects filter value. If you use `get-help get-aduser -full` you will see that `searchbase` parameter can only be used with `Filter` or `LDAPFilter` parameters. More than that neither of them accept pipeline input. `Identity` parameter accepts pipeline input by value only. so you need to use the distinguishedname property from Search-ADAccount @InactiveFilter for example distinguishedname and pass it to filter

```
$users = Search-ADAccount @InactiveFilter | %{Get-ADUser -filter {distinguishedname -eq $_.distinguishedname}  -SearchBase $OU -Property displayName, whenCreated, whenChanged}
```

I replaced your `$users=...` part with the code above and now I see no errors and  CSV file created successfully.

Replace your foreach $ou in $ous with this and check the csv file. it works on my computer

```
Foreach ($ou in $ous){
$users = (Search-ADAccount @InactiveFilter | %{Get-ADUser -filter {distinguishedname -eq $_.distinguishedname} -SearchBase $OU -Property displayName, whenCreated, whenChanged})  
    foreach ($user in $users) {
      foreach($dc in $dcs) { 
        $hostname = $dc.Name
        $last_logon_time=((Get-ADUser $user.SamAccountName | Get-ADObject -Server "$hostname" -Properties lastLogon) |?{$_.lastlogon -gt $time}) | select -ExpandProperty lastlogon
      }
      $dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime("$last_logon_time")
      $row = $user.displayName + ";" + $user.SamAccountName + ";" +
             $user.whenCreated + ";" + $user.whenChanged + ";" +
             $user.distinguishedName + ";" + $dt
      Out-File -FilePath $exportFilePath -Append -NoClobber -InputObject $row

      $last_logon_time = 0
    }
  }
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Hi Telsa, thanks for help :-) You're right, I did forget to copy the filter part, I added it now to the original post. I tried your $users code, I also get no errors but also an empty csv file with only the column names :-/

Comment: @Voilier updated the answer. please check if it works for you. This script may be very slow due to nested foreach loops and many DCs. I think Theo's solution is more neat.

Comment: Many thanks Telsa for your time and help, the last puzzle has been resolved with your help :-) I've resolved it by changing the foreach with OUs to "foreach ($element in $OUs)". Again many thanks for your input, help and time :-) Unfortunatly as I have less then 15 reputation point I cannot vote on your solution, apologies for that, as soon as I get to 15, I'll check if I can come back and vote for you :-)