# Get-ADUser unable to sort by LastLogonDate

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to sort my disabled users by the last date they logged in.

I used the following command:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "samaccountname -eq '$user' -and enabled -eq '$False'" -Properties * | 
select samaccountname, displayname, emailaddress, LastLogonDate |
Sort-Object -Property LastLogonDate
```

I'm not sure why, but it doesn't sort the `LastLogonDate` property. I keep getting an unsorted list of my disabled users.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error with the same properties selected. It's sorted from oldest to newest as expected.

Comment: `LastLogonDate` is the calculated/converted local datetime from property `lastLogonTimeStamp`. It is not replicated throughout the domain, so you need to iterate the search through the list of DC's. `(Get-ADDomainController -Filter *).Hostname | ForEach-Object {..}` and pick the latest value for LastLogonDate you find to get the most accurate date. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55707117/9898643)

Comment: BTW. Using `-Properties *` is a bad habit when you are after only a small subset of properties. In your case, do `-Properties displayname, emailaddress, LastLogonDate` as SamAccountName amongst ohthers is returned by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, I think the code you show is the part inside a loop where you iterate users, perhaps based on the input from a CSV file.

Your code only finds **one** single user and sorts that one object on its LastLogonDate.

The sorting should be done **after** you have collected all your users like

```
# capture the resulting objects from a collection of users
$result = foreach ($user in $MyListOfUserSamAccountNames) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "samaccountname -eq '$user' -and enabled -eq '$False'" -Properties displayname, emailaddress, LastLogonDate | 
    Select-Object samaccountname, displayname, emailaddress, LastLogonDate
}
# here is where you sort the result for output
$result | Sort-Object -Property LastLogonDate
```

Please bear in mind that the *calculated* property LastLogonDate (not really a AD attribute at all) is **not** replicated within the domain and to get the most accurate value, you need to iterate the domaincontrollers in your domain.

Comment: Thank you, it works. FYI, you were right about your previous comment. Adding the DCs part to my commands also worked, but this answer is way easier. Thanks for informing me about the `-properties *` usage as well.